# Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Exception on: 0 Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

В программе необходимо в зависимости от конечной цифры правильно подставить окончание, но проверку не проходит, такая ошибка, не понимаю в чем ошибка.

```
using System;

namespace Pluralize
{
    public static class PluralizeTask
    {
        public static string PluralizeRubles(int count)
        {
            // Напишите функцию склонения слова "рублей" в зависимости от предшествующего числительного count.
            count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string s = "рублей";
            if (count % 10 == 1) s = "рубль";
            if (count % 10 >= 2 && count % 10 <= 4) s = "рубля";
            if (count % 100 >= 11 & count % 100 <= 20) s = "рублей";
            if (count == 0) s = "рублей";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", count, s);
            Console.ReadKey();
            return " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы спутали форматирование в Format и в WriteLine...... у writeline вот такое:  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0#system-console-writeline(system-string-system-object-system-object)   .... и там нет никаких 0 1 и пр... А вот у Format  есть  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас попробую разобраться, отпишусь.

Comment: Переделал немного, убрал переменные вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string PluralizeRubles(int count)
    {     
        if (count % 100 > 10 && count % 100 < 20)
            return "рублей";
        if(count % 10 > 4 && count % 10 < 10)
            return "рублей";
        if(count == 0 || count % 10 == 0)
            return "рублей";
        return count % 10 == 1 ? "рубль" : "рубля";
```